# Unable to record https website which uses SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, jmeter, proxy-server, sslexception

[SSL Certificate issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0OR3.png)

Hi everyone,

While trying to record a particular https website using JMeter, i end up getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. [Please find the screenshot attached].

I have gone through solutions posted by someone who went through the same issues. But i didn't find a clear solution. Can anyone help me how to record without getting this exception.

I tried using few commands in user.properties, it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [HTTP Request sampler documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

> Note: **Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints**
>
> You may encounter the following error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints if you run a HTTPS request on a web site with a SSL certificate (itself or one of SSL certificates in its chain of trust) with a signature algorithm using MD2 (like md2WithRSAEncryption) or with a SSL certificate with a size lower than 1024 bits.
>
> This error is related to increased security in Java 7 version u16 (MD2) and version u40 (Certificate size lower than 1024 bits), and Java 8 too.
>
> To allow you to perform your HTTPS request, you can downgrade the security of your Java installation by editing the Java jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms property. Remove the MD2 value or the constraint on size, depending on your case.
>
> This property is in this file:
>
> `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`

See [Bug 56357 - Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints: Adding a note to indicate how to remove of the Java installation these new security constraints](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56357) issue for more details.

---

You may find easier using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732849-Chrome-Extension-Record) as an alternative option of recording a JMeter test.

Comment: though it didn't solve my problem..thanks for your insights :)